# Стили для элементов, которые создаются через jQuery

Tags: jquery

Скриптом добавляются новые элементы

```
<!--[if IE 7]> 
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.breadcrumbs li a').not('.breadcrumbs li:first-child a').before('&raquo;&nbsp;');
        });
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Как задать для этих элементов цвет? Они получаются по умолчанию черными.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что если оформить их в тэг span с указанным цветом?

```
<!--[if IE 7]> 
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.breadcrumbs li a').not('.breadcrumbs li:first-child a').before('<span style="color: red">&raquo;&nbsp;</span>');
    });
</script>
```

<![endif]-->

Comment: да, спасибо, работает.